# Call function inside onPaymentMethodReceived(obj) method of Braintree

Tags: javascript, braintree

I am trying to call the function in `onPaymentMethodReceived:function (obj)` method but I am getting an error the obj contains the payments nonce.

My JS code is

```
 this.braintree.setup(this.clientToken, "dropin", {
   container: "dropin-container",
   onPaymentMethodReceived:function (obj) {
     console.log("nonce  "+obj.nonce);
     this.ckeckoutClick(obj.nonce)  //I want call this function which is post request to server//
   }
 })
```

my HTML is

```
<form id="checkout">
  <div id="dropin-container"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Place Order">
</form>
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `this` inside the function use `() =>` instead of `function ()`

```
   this.braintree.setup(this.clientToken, "dropin", {
        container: "dropin-container",
        onPaymentMethodReceived: (obj) => {
            console.log("nonce  "+obj.nonce);
            this.ckeckoutClick(obj.nonce)  //I want call this function which is post request to server//
         }
    })
```

otherwise `this.checkoutClick()` will call `checkoutClick` on `braintree` or from wherever the callback is called.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it helps me a lot I invested more time to figure out thanks you made my day :)